# Sending big array over usart

Tags: c, memory, avr, usart, progmem

i am working with AVR controller atmega16 having 16kb of flash and 1kb of Sram.i have stored data in an static array i.e `static char raw_data[15361];`and trying to send it over usart using following function:

```
void USART_TxChar(  char data)                      /* Data transmitting function */
{
    UDR = data;                                     /* Write data to be transmitting in UDR */
    while (!(UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)));                   /* Wait until data transmit and buffer get empty */
}

void USART_SendString(  char *str)                  /* Send string of USART data function */ 
{
    int i=0;                                                                    
    while (str[i]!=0)
    {
        USART_TxChar(str[i]);                       /* Send each char of string till the NULL */
        i++;
    }
}
```

my issue is when ever i put my array in usart it is showing memory full.   `USART_SendString(raw_data);`.i searched online and find out that my function is loading all of the array to RAM hence leading to an error.i found there is a way though which you can send data stored in flash over usart using `PROGMEM attribute` but it works only for `const string type`.
so how should i send my data stored in flash memory over usart without leading to memory full error??

Comment: Store your array in flash (PROGMEM) and rewrite your SendString function to `void USART_SendString(const char *str)`. Btw, `static char` doesn't mean it will be in flash.

Comment: @tilz0R i tried that also but it says that i have to make the array `const`.which i cant because prior sending data over usart i am storing my sensor data in that array.making it const i wont be able to add values to that array.

Comment: "1kb of Sram" and then  "static char raw_data[15361];". Your array is 15 times larger than your available RAM. Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: @Lundin that's why i am using static keyword to store it in flash memory instead of RAM,that i have verified it by debugging the code.

Comment: @pranjal khanduri I afraid you do not understand meaning of the word static. All data is always stored in the flash but then copied to the RAM unless you instructed the compiler & startup code to do not. AVR have separate address spaces for the code and data, and to access the data in the flash special machine code instructions are needed.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 can you please guide me where i can find these instructions.

Comment: <avr/pgmspace.h> and keyword PROGMEM or using named address spaces which is more natural.

Answer (score 1):

static does not mean PROGMEM. You need to place & access them in/from the flash memory. From gcc 4.8 you can use named address spaces

```
 const __flash char raw_data[15361];
```

and

```
 void USART_SendString(const __flash char *str)
```

Comment: if i make my `raw_data[]` as `const` i am not able to modify or write anything to it.hence i wont be store anything to it. Moreover `PROGMEM` do not have any write operation.

Comment: of course not. But there is no way to have 15k  bytes in the RAM on the device which has 1k. There are no miracles. You need to store only part of it in the RAM or change the device to something more modern.

Comment: so there is no way  to save data  in my flash (15k or less than that) ,and later on sending it over usart (reading byte by byte from Flash Memory)at run time.and repeating this process again and again.

Comment: but you want to write it. I do not understand you. If you want to send constant data known during the compilation it is possible, Otherwise not. Remember as well that you only have 16k of the FLASH and not too much is left for your program itself.

Comment: My data is not constant it is coming from sensor(accelerometer sensor readings).which is getting stored in `Raw_data[]` array.As i am having 16k flash so i decided to fill it upto 15k(can be modified) and later send it byte by byte over usart.so that it wont load the whole array into the RAM.this is what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: so can me suggest me any other hardware or the points that i should look for while selecting hardware for my this task.

Comment: @pranjalkhanduri: You could use external memory to store your sensor data. Then read and send it in smaller blocks like 100 byte or so.

Comment: @Rev1.0 using the external memory for this kind of micro is an overkill. for the same price as avr he will get a proper cortex with enough resources

Comment: @pranjalkhanduri Why do you need a buffer size of **15kb**??? That's enormous. Most likely your specification does not make the slightest sense and that's the root of all your problems.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: I was not suggesting a SRAM extension, maybe you thought that. Something simple like SPI NAND flash would be totally sufficient to put the data somewhere. I don't think he requires fast access.

Comment: @Lundin my sensor has a FIFO buffer of 1024 bytes i am reading it and storing it in `raw_data[]` array.i planned it to read 15 times making 15360 bytes store it in flash and then send byte by byte over usart.idea was to store as much as data i can in one go.

Comment: @pranjalkhanduri "idea was to store as much as data i can in one go" This doesn't make any sense. If your MCU doesn't do anything with the data, but just forwards it, there is no apparent need to allocate a buffer. The bottleneck in this system is most likely the UART tx, so reading data faster than what the UART is capable of sending won't give any benefits.